# Fax PDF Adobe Livecycle

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, livecycle, fax

I have been trying to figure out how to fax a pdf using Adobe Livecycle ES4.

Is there any API that would allow me to fax a pdf on the click of a submit button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adobe LiveCycle does not come with any built in components for sending pdfs via fax. You would need to install a custom Java component into LiveCycle to handle faxing. You can either write the component yourself or find a 3rd party that can provide or create a custom component for you.